# how to reset combobox to default value after clear the form

Tags: jquery, combobox

it's a combobox(easyui) in the form and i want to reset all the form

here is the code:

```
$("#resetButtonId").click(function(){
    $("#formId").find("input").val("")  ;
    $('#comboboxId').combobox("reload") ;
// or $('#comboboxId').combobox("setValue","default option")
});
```

it works at first time
but when the combobox already reset to default value and click the button again,the value of combobox shows nothing

i try to use combobox("getText") and it shows the value is correct(default option),but show nothing at the page.